# problem with form php and sql

Tags: php, sql, forms, syntax-error

Ok, so im new in php and sql, and I have this form that submits some names and cities into a database.

I managed to do it, but once a hit the submit button, i get an error:

*"Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1"*

but, when i check in phpmyadmin, the **new record is there!!**, so im not sure what's wrong, thats the problem.

this is the code:

```
<?php
   mysql_connect("localhost", "name", "pass") or die(mysql_error());
   echo "Connection to the server was successful!<br/>";

   mysql_select_db("db_name") or die(mysql_error());
   echo "Database was selected!<br/>";



    $resultComuna = mysql_query("SELECT idComuna, nombre FROM comuna ORDER BY nombre ASC");
    $resultGiro = mysql_query("SELECT idGiro, nombre FROM giro ORDER BY nombre ASC");

?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>TEST</title>
</head>
<body>
    <br/><br/>
    <form name="form" method="POST" action="test_action.php">
        <div align="center">

    <!--/////////////////  input nombre ////////////////////////  -->
            NOMBRE CLIENTE:
            <input name="nombreCliente" type="text" maxlength="30" size="40"></>

    <!-- ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->

    <!-- ////////////////////drop box para giro ///////////////////// -->
            GIRO:
            <select name="giro">
            <?php
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultGiro)){
                echo "<option value=\"".$row['idGiro']."\">".$row['nombre']."</option><br/>";
            }
            ?>      
            </select>
    <!-- ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->

    <!-- ////////////// dropbox para comunas //////////////////////// -->
            COMUNA:
            <select name="comunas">
            <?php
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultComuna)){

                echo "<option value=\"".$row['idComuna']."\">".$row['nombre']."</option><br/>";
            }
            ?>      
            </select>
    <!-- ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->

        <input type="submit" value="Ingresar"> </>

        </div>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

and the test_action.php is:

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "name", "pass");
    if (!$con)
      {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
      }

    mysql_select_db("data_base", $con);


$query = mysql_query("SELECT max(idNombre)+1 as id FROM nombre");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$idMax = $row['id'];


    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO nombre VALUES ('".$idMax."','".$_POST['comunas']."',".$_POST['giro'].",'".$_POST['nombreCliente']."')");

    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
      {
      die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
      }
    echo "record added";

    mysql_close($con)
?>
```

Comment: Replace all the pointless code you posted and post the **raw** sql query that is passed to mysql, without any php or html code.

Comment: The syntax error says it: one of your SQL-Statements isn't formed properly. Try echoing all the SQL-Statements, then you'll find the SQL-Error.

Comment: Escape your inputs! There's an SQL injection lurking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're inserting the ID in single quotes:

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO nombre VALUES ('".$idMax."','".$_POST['comunas']."',".$_POST['giro'].",'".$_POST['nombreCliente']."')");
```

Can you provide the table structure? ID is an integer or a varchar there?

Comment: This cannot be an issue. Mysql automatically casts the types.

Comment: this is the table structure:

`CREATE TABLE `nombre` (

  `idNombre` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,

  `Comuna_idComuna` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Giro_idGiro` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(255) collate latin1_general_ci default NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY  (`idNombre`),

  KEY `Nombre_FKIndex3` (`Comuna_idComuna`),
  KEY `Nombre_FKIndex1` (`Giro_idGiro`)

)`

Comment: Can you echo the sql command. I guess something is wrong in the value that you're getting form `$_POST`.

Comment: Sounds like that would be a problem solved by parameterization.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing test_action.php to:

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "name", "pass");
    if (!$con)
        {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
        }

    mysql_select_db("data_base", $con);

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT max(idNombre)+1 as id FROM nombre");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    $idMax = $row['id'];

    $query = "INSERT INTO nombre VALUES ('".$idMax."','".$_POST['comunas']."',".$_POST['giro'].",'".$_POST['nombreCliente']."')";
    $sql = mysql_query($query);
    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysql_error().'<br>query: '.$query);
    }
    echo "record added";

    mysql_close($con);
?>
```

It helps for debugging